# Does a Banshee's Veil Shield prevent spell damage?

Tags: league-of-legends

Does a Banshee's Veil Shield prevent spell damage? Like it can prevent damage from champs spells?

Answer (score 9):

**[Banshee's Veil](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Banshee%27s_Veil)** prevents any negative magic effect, including damage. This applies to all spells, not just those cast by champions.

I've tested this with three of [Baron Nashor's spells:](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Baron_Nashor)

- **Wrath of the Ancients** deals magic damage and applies a debuff which increases magic damage taken. It stacks up to ten times.
- **Sweeping Blow** knocks all champions away from the Baron by a set range. This range is equivalent to the distance between the Baron and the entrance to his locale.
- An unnamed ability which inflicts knockup and slow similar to Cho'Gath's Rupture.

Banshee's Veil was activated by each of the above spells.

#### Trivia:

- Banshee's Veil does not negate summoner spells  Ignite and  Exhaust.
- Banshee's Veil will not block damage from persistent AoE spells such as: Anivia's  Glacial Storm, Nasus's Spirit Fire, and Fiddle's Ultimate.
- Banshee's Veil will not block passive damage over time effects from abilities such as  Brand's  Blaze, and Gangplank's  Grog Soaked Blade.
- Banshee's Veil will [block Gangplank's Parrrley](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=79884) (confirmed through experience as well). This is because Parrrley it's a spell that mimics a physical ranged attack, so it's intended to be blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Banshee's Veil, when active, will block one entire ability.  This includes any CC or damage attached to said ability.

Answer (score 0):

The shield it provides ever 45 seconds does block the damage and any status effects that ability provides. For example, Banshee's Veil would block both the damage and the bind from Morgana's Dark Binding.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the shield itelf blocks one spell every 45 seconds. It also provides additional Magic Resistance (MR).

Answer (score 0):

It negates the damage from the spell it blocks. Along with the magic resist, it makes a great defensive item against burst champions

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Banshee's Veil Blocks one negative spell every 45 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

It blocks ONE negative spell.

That means if there is a spell that hits multiple times it will NOT take damage from the FIRST spell hit, or in some cases (Ahri's Fox Fire) it can block up to two of them if they hit at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it will even block deathfire grasp from a burst AP carry, so it can protect against a lot of damage.  However it is so easy to pop before a teamfight happens so it makes it not such a great item.

Answer (score -2):

The vield does block a spell while you have a bubble around you, but you should note that it doesn't block -every- spell. Only things that deal magic damage, and only things that are activated by qwe or r, and only single target, or targeted aoe.

For instance, the block list (Not inclusvie)

Shens Q
Morganas Q
Niddalees throw
Ryzes q, w, and e
Singed throw
Sions stun
Pantheons stun

What it does not block at things that don't specifically target you, or things that deal physical damage

For instance, Gangplanks q is physical and is not blocked by banshees. Morganas w doesn't pop it, because it just deals aoe damage. Things that target specific champions, but don't deal physical damage, is blocked. Some champions, like talon, deal physical damage with their spells, and can't be blocked by it.

All CC's and Snares that are not slows are garunteed to be blocked. Some slows still cannot be blocked, because they slow on the ground, and not your specifically. For instance, kogmalls throw will have the damage blocked, but the spell on the ground will still be active. Its important to know if it targets a player, or if it targets the ground.

Comment: Banshee's Veil will block Gangplank's Parrrley, Source for this, and by experience too. Because Parrrley it's a spell that mimics a physical ranged attack. so its intended to be blocked. This is why I -1 you, sorry.